# How can you not do the `using namespace std;` eqivalent in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

Basically, literally every VHDL file I've ever seen has a header of something like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
```

This seems to splat the entire contents of the relevant library into the current namespace-analog (whatever VHDL calls it, it doesn't seem to have an explicit name in the VHDL manual, or I'm reading it wrong).

Is there any way to *not* just splat everything into the current namespace?

Removing the `.all` postfix seems to partially work (types have to be specified by their full paths), but it seems to break all operator overloading done by the relevant types.

Comment: see the `all` on those use clauses? Delete that and use qualified names instead. (You may have trouble with overloaded operators, there's no equivalent to `use type std_logic;` as far as I know)

Comment: @BrianDrummond - That seems to break all the math and logic. For example, "not" no longer works, etc...

Comment: They will still work : but you may have to call them with explicit syntax or import them explicitly : `use ieee.std_logic_1164.not` perhaps.

Comment: Operator equality is also broken by the change, somehow. For example, `data_valid = '1'`, where `data_valid` is a `std_logic` no longer compiles. Incidentally, `ieee.std_logic_1164.not` produces a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to expand on the comments, all you need to do is delete the `.all` from the `use` clause and only import what you need.

If that includes operators and literals, the compiler will tell you what is missing...

> ghdl -a test_qualified.vhd
>   test_qualified.vhd:14:10: no function declarations for operator "not"
>   test_qualified.vhd:15:10: can't match character literal '0' with type std_ulogic
>   test_qualified.vhd:15:21: no function declarations for operator "="
>   test_qualified.vhd:15:30: can't match character literal '1' with type std_ulogic
>   ghdl: compilation error

Simply import those too.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164;
use ieee.std_logic_1164."not";
use ieee.std_logic_1164."=";
use ieee.std_logic_1164.'0';
-- use ieee.std_logic_1164.'1';

entity test_qualified is
end test_qualified;

architecture test of test_qualified is

signal a,b,c : ieee.std_logic_1164.std_logic;

begin

    a <= not b;
    c <= '0' when a = b else ieee.std_logic_1164.'1';

end test;
```

Apparently, not many people feel they need this level of control of the namespaces. But it is possible.

If I found myself repeating this fine control in different compilation units, I'd learn about VHDL-2008's `context` keyword and declare a `context` specific to my application.

Comment: Urgh. How horribly ugly. VHDL seems like it's stuck in the 70s.

Comment: I think you commented before I finished the answer. It seems like you want it to guess what you want it to bring into the namespace or leave out, without your having to tell it. What language actually does that again?

Comment: C++ (and every other modern OOP language) allows attaching type operators to the type, so the lookup requires zero additional use type statements. It shouldn't have to "guess", the types are obviously defined, and if there is no way to overload the operators that doesn't just stuff it in the current namespace without attaching it to anything, that's poor design.

Comment: I don't want it to do any guessing, I just want the compiler to actually be able to do very pedestrian inferences. Or recognize the last 20+ years of advances in modern language design. Also, pascal-style syntax is ghastly. Case insensitivity? Really?

Comment: Fair enough. VHDL isn't really *for* object oriented programming, though there have been proposals to get it there, which would help with complex testbenches. From my first comment the "use type" notation to make the operators visible - added to VHDL's ancestor language (Ada) in either 1995 or 2005 - could easily be added in the next revision of VHDL if there was any demand for it. Your question is, so far, the only demand I've seen.

Comment: I suspect I'm mostly just kind of culture-shocking learning VHDL stuff after a year+ away from doing anything hardware related. It seems to me that OOP-like programming approaches are ideally suited to hardware descriptions, as you're literally describing objects instantiated in the FPGA fabric/ASIC.

Comment: VHDL just *feels* old as a language (well, it is), and it seems like there is very very little innovation in the HDL field. I'll probably wind up switching to MyHDL once I feel (somewhat) comfortable with VHDL. Most of my issues boil down to the excessive verbosity, or the extreme dumbness of the language tokenization/parsing step in (at least) Xilinx's toolchain. We'll see if I get irritated enough to write a preprocessor that at least gives me some syntactic sugar.